# How to extract the last 3 indices numbers before a specific category

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing, categories

**UPDATE**

I have the following dataset, and I wish to get a list that includes the last three indices before 'YES' label. 
My dataset:

```html
i            category
0               NO
1               NO
2               NO
3               NO
4               NO
5               YES
6               YES
7               YES
8               NO
9               NO
10              NO
11              YES
12              YES
```

I expect the outcome to be:

list=[2,3,4,8,9,10]

**Please note that YES usually occur in consecutive range of samples (2-6 samples). I wish to get the the last three indices before the first YES in the range.**

P.S: The dataset was stored in a csv file and I imported by using pandas

Comment: How is the dataset represented in python? Add that info to the question please

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh as pandas. This data is in an csv and I imported it using pandas

Comment: Add all that info into the question

Comment: What about if there are not 3 indices before YES?

Comment: @rpanai There will always be at least 3 before YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most pythonic way, but I couldn't think of a way to do this without a a for loop and some slicing, feels like a hacky method:

```
a = df[((df.category.ne(df.category.shift()))==True) & (df.category == 'YES')].index


indices = []
for x in a:
    indices.append(df.iloc[slice(max(0, x-3), min(x, len(df)))])
new_df = pd.concat(indices) # if you wanted this as a df.

list(new_df.index)


[2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I updated my question . This would work only when YES is labeled in one single sample. However, in ,my dataset YES is labeled in a range of consecutive samples, so this code would print the indices of the last three samples before every YES in the range. howevr, I need the last three indices of only the first YES in the range

Comment: @AlexDavies edited answer :) make sure you think about your question a little more, some people would get annoyed that they wasted time

Comment: @AlexDavies no problem, best of luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, as you stated on your comment, that there are always at least 3 items before every YES. A possible solution will be

```py
import pandas as pd

flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame({"category":['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO',
                               'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO',
                               'NO','YES','NO']})
# take only indices where YES occurs
idx = df[df["category"]=="YES"].index

# for every i in idx take the previuos 3 indices
lst = [list(range(i-3, i)) for i in idx]

# flatten lst
lst = flatten(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However, there is a slight issue. It is my bad, I didn't clarify it in the question. In my dataset, 'YES' is labeled in a consecutive samples, it is not only at one sample. I will edit the question accordingly @rpanai

Comment: @AlexDavies I added my answer after explicitly asked if that was the case. If you edit your question do so after an **UPDATE** note please.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that's easy to read and does what you want.
it iterates over the indices of the list and pulls out what you need.

the second for loops is to simply flatten the double list from the result list.

```py
li= ['1','2','3','4','YES','6','7','8','9','0','YES']
result = []
for x in range(len(li)):
  if li[x] is 'YES':
    result.append(li[x-3:x])


final= []
for x in result:
  for y in x:
    final.append(y)
```

final = ['2', '3', '4', '8', '9', '0']